# Почему imagick не открывает некоторые pdf файлы?

Tags: php, yii, imagemagick, imagick, php5-fpm

php 5.6
imagemagick (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.4).
php5.6-imagick (3.4.3~rc2-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1).

В общем такая задача разделить pdf документы на png по страницам. Cкрипт работает, но есть такие pdf файлы, которые не загружаются через readImage(); При этом я не славлеваю ни каких исключений. При запуске я говорю set_time_limit(0). Нормальные файлы могут конвертироваться в течении неограниченого времени.

php5,6-pfm не выводит ничего в логи. Продолжает работать.

Сначала думал, что файлы слишком большого размера, хотя такое бывает и с pdf размером и 100+Мб, так и с малыми 200Кб например. Ничего общего не нашел между этими странными ПДФками.

Так вот, как контролировать работу скрипта, и сделать так, чтобы если встречается такой pdf файл, то переходить к другому?

Comment: Приведите пример скрипта, так будет проще вам помочь